# Gulp. Node V4. Typeerror (only on watch): Path must be a string

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, watch, gulp-watch

All tasks executes well, except **watchh** where use function `gulp.watch()`. I really don't know what should I do. Over the internet same error issued with NodeJS v6. But I have latest 4 major ver.
Have a gulp file

```
// gulp declarations
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    pug = require('gulp-pug'),
    copy = require('gulp-copy'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

// other declaration
var sq = require('streamqueue'); //allow to write results into stream, rather file output

/*
* Complete result in a single css file for public using. */
gulp.task('fincss', function () {
    var convertFromScssToCssAndConcat =
        gulp.src('./src/sass/*.scss')
            .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError));

    var minifyAndConcatExistingCss =
        gulp.src('./src/css/*.css');

    return sq({objectMode: true},
        minifyAndConcatExistingCss, convertFromScssToCssAndConcat)
        .pipe(concat('final.min.css'))
        .pipe(uglifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'));
});

gulp.task('pug', function () {
    return gulp.src(['src/pug/*.pug', '!src/pug/component_*.pug'])
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});

gulp.task('watchh', function () {
    gulp.watch('./src/css/*.css', ['fincss']);
    gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', ['fincss']);
    gulp.watch('./src/pug/*.pug', ['pug']);
});
```

npm dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
"gulp-pug": "^3.0.4",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
"gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-uglifycss": "^1.0.6",
"gulp-watch": "^4.3.9",
"semantic-ui-css": "^2.2.2",
"streamqueue": "^1.1.1"
  },
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been found only by `gulp-watch` plugin.
First, add

```
watch = require('gulp-watch');
```

Second, the Task is

```
gulp.task('watch', ['fincss'], function () {
    watch([<pathes_here>], function () {
        gulp.run('fincss');
    });
});
```

Thanks for attention to everyone.